# Expectation of boys and girls.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Consider $10$ boys and $8$ girls to be seated in a straight line. Let $X$, a random variable, be the number of girls having boys on both sides. What is $E(X)$?

My try:

For $X=8$, $P(X=8)=\frac{16\times17\times18}{\frac{18!}{10!8!}}.$

$X=7$ isn't possible.

I have trouble evaluating probabilities of other possible values for $X$. Help appreciated!

Comment: Important lesson: if you are asked to find an expectation then *firstly* check whether you can find it without chasing on the distribution. If that seems not possible then you can fall back on the distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the girls the numbers $1,2,\dots,8$ and for $i\in\{1,\dots,8\}$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if girl $i$ will have boys on both sides and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then: $$X=\sum_{i=1}^8X_i$$

With linearity of expectation and symmetry we find: $$\mathbb EX=8\mathbb EX_1=8P(X_1=1)$$

Can you find $P(X_1=1)$ yourself?

Comment: $P(X_1=1)=\frac{16}{18}\frac{10}{17}\frac{9}{16}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.